# Expresión regular para password con acentos y eñes

Tags: regex

Tengo una expresion regular que no sé como modificarla para que me admita acentos y ñ.

**La expresion es**

```
var pattern = /^(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-Z])(?=\w*[a-z])\S{8,16}$/;
```

Esta expresión fuerza a que una password tenga como requisitos mínimos:
Una mayúscula
Una minúscula
Un número
Longitud entre 8 y 16.

**He intentado modificarla de esta forma**

```
var pattern = /^(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚÜ])(?=\w*[a-zñáéíóúü])\S{8,16}$
```

pero esto no funciona.

Comment: En las preguntas sobre regex siempre se pide que aclares que lenguaje estas usando (puede haber ligeras variaciones en la regex a usar)

Comment: Deberías colocar cuales son todas las reglas.

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente expresión regular es capaz de validar los passwords de la manera que necesitas:

`^(?=.*[a-záéíóúñ])(?=.*[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÑ])(?=.*[0-9])\S{8,16}$`

Puedes probarla aquí: https://regex101.com/r/ChcS1q/1

Nota: Actualmente no permites espacios en blanco en el password. Si quisieras permitirlos podrías utilizar esta otra expresión regular, muy parecida a la anterior donde lo único que cambia es el final:

`^(?=.*[a-záéíóúñ])(?=.*[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÑ])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,16}$`

Comment: probablemente quieran agregar la `ü`

Answer (score 0):

Esta parte es la que te va a permitir añadir acentos (en mayúscula y minúscula) y eñes:

```
/^(?:[\u00C0-\u00FF]+)$/
```

Aquí tienes el [regex](https://regex101.com/r/BKm2PT/2) para probar.

Comment: Gracias pero no sé como incluir lo que propones en mi expresión. Lo he intentado sin éxito. Mi expresión determinada que una contraseña tenga una mayúscula, una minúscula y un número como mínimo. Y cuando digo una mayúscula quisiera que fuera al conjunto A-Z más ÑÁÉÍÓÚÜ y minúscula el conjunto a-z más ñáéíóúü.

Answer (score 0):

Te puede servir esta expresión regular:

```
/^[a-záÁéÉìÌíÍóÓúÚñÑA-Z0-9()¿?,.]+(\s+[a-záÁéÉìÌíÍóÓúÚñÑA-Z0-9()¿?,.]+)*$/
```

Comment: Por favor, sea un poco más educado al momento de responder, lea el [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) y también [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), saludos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe el funcionamiento de la expresión regular. Además, OP (el autor de la pregunta) no aclaró en qué lenguaje está trabajando. Lee [answer].